# Rich Text Format Tags for Hiding and Un-hiding

Tags: hide, rtf, richtext

I would like to hide part of the text in my RichTextBox. I know that \v is the start of a hiding section. But how do I unhide ? For example if I want to hide the word "big" in the string "hello big world" so that "hello  world" is visible:

---

```
text              : "hello big world"
RTF so far        : "hello \v big world"
result            : "hello "
wanted result  -> : "hello  world"
doesn't work      : "hello \v big\v  world"
```

---

Is there a way ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution by Alex K. is probably better but I'm adding this solution I just found because it also works. `\plain` resets the text style back to defaults:

```
hello \v big\plain  world
```

Yet another solution (actually used by the RichTextBoxes): `\v0` disables just the hiding

```
hello \v big\v0  world
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to use curly braces to group the code;

```
"hello {\v big} world"
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to do that before but I put the opening brace behind the tag like in LaTeX `\v{}`